# htaccess is not being recognized on ec2 suse instance web server

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, amazon-ec2, suse

Alright here's the deal: my .htaccess file is not working at all

My server setup is SuSE on an Amazon EC2 Instance
- Apache is setup, mod_rewrite is loaded and enabled
- In my http.conf I have:

```
<Directory />
    Options None
    AllowOverride All
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
</Directory>

<Directory /srv/www/htdocs/>
  AllowOverride All
</Directory>

# use .htaccess files for overriding,
AccessFileName .htaccess
# and never show them
<Files ~ "^\.ht">
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
</Files>
```

- On the server I have CI install, .htacces does nothing it's supposed too. For example, to test to see if it works I created a .htacess that says 'deny from all', was still able to access the pages.
- I have restarted apache each time I made a change to the configuration file.

What could be causing my htaccess files not be recognized?

Answer (score 1):

Was editing the wrong config file,

Needed to edit default-server.conf and not httpd.conf for the changes to happen